# How to select all Jira issues with type "Test" that match the components in the current sprint?

Tags: components, jira, jql

We are managing our functional tests in Jira (using Zephyr plugin). Every test is an issue with type "Test".
On every sprint, we aim to execute the functional tests for every component that is affected by the stories in that sprint.

To make this process a bit easier, I am trying to create a filter that returns all issues of the "Test" type that have a component that is matched by at least 1 issue in the current sprint. After some researching i still haven't been able to do this.

Comment: Are these issues in the sprint itself?

Comment: No, they are not. We have a general set of tests that are linked to the components, so we can reuse them for every sprint.

Comment: So they are not even linked to the sprint issues. I had the idea of getting them as `Sprint in openSprints()`, but this way it's a no-go.

Comment: Yep i was looking into that, but since the only link is through component it's not possible. i was hoping for something like "component in openSprintComponents()".

Comment: Well, if you're into some coding, you can make one: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/10399041/script-runner-creating-a-custom-jql-function